# simple search within an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, search

I want to be able to search within my Micropost model. Microposts have artist and song attributes. I am tagging these microposts use acts_as_taggable gem.

Micropost Model:

```
def self.search(search)
  arel = order('created_at')
  arel = arel.where('UPPER(artist) LIKE UPPER(?) OR UPPER(song) LIKE UPPER(?)', "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%").order('created_at') if search.present?
  arel
end
```

This code allows me to search for artist and song but how can I also search for tags?

Micropost.find(1).tags returns [#ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag id: 18, name: "rock", #ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag id: 3, name: "rap"]

Micropost.find(1).tags.map(&:name) returns an array like ["rock", "rap"]

How can I query a micropost's tags with it isn't in it's table as well as artist and song? Thank you.

Something like adding another where() like?

```
where(self.tags.map(&:name), 'LIKE UPPER(?)', "%#{search}%")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you include a link to the gem you're using? there are a few out there. This one has it built in: https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on

Speaking more generally, tags are often best implemented as a separate table then joined to the objects as opposed to stored with the objects themselves. This way you can join from the tags table to find the objects.

More specifically, your example near the end looks backwards. You have:

```
where(self.tags.map(&:name), 'LIKE UPPER(?)', "%#{search}%")
```

But you (IMHO) should be trying to start with the tag and map back to the object. Something like:

```
Tag.where('LIKE UPPER(?)', "%#{search}%").microposts
```